# Proof that $C_{\text{fin}}(X)$ separates points

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, analysis

Consider the one point compactification $\bar{\mathbb{R}} = \mathbb{R} \cup \{+\infty\}$. Given a countable set $T$, we define the topological space $X = \bar{\mathbb{R}}^{T}$. This is a topological space when equipped with the product topology. It is also compact, since every $\bar{\mathbb{R}}$ is compact.
Next, we introduce the following set:
$$C_{\text{fin}}(X) = \{f: X \to \mathbb{R}: \text{$f$ is continuous and depends only on finitely many entries of $x = (x_{\alpha})_{\alpha \in T} \in X$}\}$$
I want to prove that $C_{\text{fin}}(X)$ is a subalgebra of $C(X)$ which separates points. The fact that it is a subalgebra is easily checked. However, I am a bit unsure how to prove that is separate points. My first guess would be to consider projection mappings: given $x \neq y$ elements of $X$, there exists some $\alpha \in T$ such that $x_{\alpha} \neq y_{\alpha}$. Then, a first natural guess would be to consider the projection $\pi_{\alpha}$ on $X$ which projects to $x \in X$ to $x_{\alpha}$. The problem is: such a projection is not a real-valued function, but instead it takes values on $\bar{\mathbb{R}}$, since entries are allowed to be $+\infty$. It is not clear to me, however, how to define projections without taking the infinity into account. Maybe there is another easy and explicit function I can use to show that $C_{\text{fin}}(X)$ separates points?

Comment: For the **one point** compactification, I would not call the extra point $+\infty$.  There is no sense that it is "positive".  Maybe just call it $\infty$.  Also: your definition of $C_{\text{fin}}(X)$ does not say that $f$ is continuous?

Comment: Yes, it should be continuous! Many thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\overline{\mathbb{R}}$ is normal and so by Tietze extension theorem there is $f_\alpha:\overline{\mathbb{R}}\to\mathbb{R}$ such that $f_\alpha(x_\alpha)=0$ and $f_\alpha(y_\alpha)=1$ (btw, we don't have to use Tietze here, it is possible to construct such map directly, but it is faster that way). And so the function you are looking for is composition of $f_\alpha$ with projection $\pi_\alpha:X\to X_\alpha$.

Comment: Thanks! I did not know Tietze Theorem. Maybe you could add a few details of how to prove it without using this theorem? It would be really helpful.

Comment: The direct construction goes like this. First we may assume $x_\alpha=0$ and $y_\alpha=1$. That's because $\overline{\mathbb{R}}$ is a circle, and so we can rotate and stretch it to get desired points. Then $f(t)=t$ for $t\in [0,1]$. And for points outside of $[0,1]$ you have to wrap it around so that negative and positive infinites (which are glued into single infinity) meet at say $1/2$. Does it help?

Comment: That being said I encourage you to read about Tietze. It is a classical and very important result in topology.

Comment: Okay, I see your point. I was reading about Tietze Theorem. It generalizes Urysohn Lemma. I know Urysohn Lemma, so I might change a bit your idea to prove the result. If $x \neq y$, I can take the disjoint sets $\{x\}$ and $\{y\}$, which are subsets of $X$. By Urysohn Lemma, there exists a function $f$ such that $f(x) = 0$ and $f(y) = 1$. Same idea, right?

Comment: Yes, sure. Urysohn works here as well.

Answer (score 1):

Since the topology of $\overline{\mathbb{R}} = \mathbb{R} \cup \{\infty\}$ is metrizable, we can find a metric $d$ that realizes the topology of $\overline{\mathbb{R}}$. (We can explicitly find such a metric, for instance by noting that $\overline{\mathbb{R}}$ is homeomorphic to $\mathbb{S}^1$ via the stereographic projection.)

Now let $x, y \in X$ with $x \neq y$, and let $\alpha \in T$ be an index at which $x_{\alpha} \neq y_{\alpha}$. Then consider the function

$$ f : X \to \mathbb{R}, \qquad f(z) = d(z_{\alpha}, x_{\alpha}). $$

Then $f \in C_{\text{fin}}(X)$ such that $f(x) = 0$ but $f(y) > 0$. Hence $f$ separates $x$ and $y$.